# Composition of Left Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know what a left coset is, but I'm still confused upon composition of left cosets. Could someone provide an example for better understanding of this concept?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example: Consider the subgroup $6\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$.  Let's take the two cosets, say, $3 + 6\mathbb{Z}$ and $5 + 6\mathbb{Z}$.  The sum (or composition) of these two cosets is the set obtained by adding all possible combinations $x + y$, where $x \in 3 + 6\mathbb{Z}$ and $y \in 5 + 6\mathbb{Z}$.  For example, if $x = 3 + 6(8)$ and $y = 5 + 6(-2)$, then $x + y = 51 + (-7) = 44$, which, you'll notice is equal to $2 + 42 = 2 + 6(7)$.

In general: $(3 + 6j) + (5 + 6k) = 8 + 6(j + k) = 2 + 6(j + k + 1)$, which shows that $(3 + 6\mathbb{Z}) + (5 + 6\mathbb{Z}) \subset 2 + 6\mathbb{Z}$.  And, in fact, it's easy to show that the two sets are actually equal.

As a good exercise, you should work through similar examples with the integers, and then turn to other, say, finite, groups.  In particular: what happens when you try to do this for a non-abelian group and a non-normal subgroup?